# ReferenceError: BASE_URL is not defined, Angular JS dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, dependency-injection, module

I have two angular modules, starter.constant which store all constant, and starter.services where the controllers are.

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngTouch', 'ngCordova', 'ngStorage', 'starter.core'])

.factory('examService', ["$http", "$ionicLoading", 'BASE_URL', function($http, $ionicLoading) {
  return {
    httpGet: function(url, data) {
      $ionicLoading.show();
      return $http.get(BASE_URL + url, data);
    },
    httpUpdate: function(url, data) {
      $ionicLoading.show();
      return $http.patch(BASE_URL + url, data);
    },
    httpPost: function(url, data) {
      $ionicLoading.show();
      return $http.post(BASE_URL + url, data);
    },
    httpDelete: function(url, data) {
      $ionicLoading.show();
      return $http.delete(BASE_URL + url, data);
    }
  };
}])
```

Constants Module:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
    angular
      .module('starter.core',[])
      .constant('BASE_URL', 'http://example');
})();
```

However, when I go to the browser I get the following error :

```
ReferenceError: BASE_URL is not defined
```

The line that throw this error is in httpGet function

Any suggest or advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject `BASE_URL` into your factory function:

```
factory('examService', ["$http", "$ionicLoading", 'BASE_URL', function($http, $ionicLoading, BASE_URL) {
```

Comment: There is no need include BASE_URL before the function, am I right? I mean, I can do  factory('examService', ["$http", "$ionicLoading", function($http, $ionicLoading, BASE_URL) ?????

Comment: @CheBay It would work, but you should inject all your dependencies. This way angular would know which variable is used at that location, when your code gets minified in production.